# r programming --- twitteR OAuthFactory object error

Tags: r

I am setting up an R session to be able to download twitter feeds. I got stumbled on the very step with R citing 'object OAuthFactory not found'. I have all the libraries needed for the program and packages installed: Here is my code

```
my.key <- "xxx"

#consumer secret
my.secret <- "xxx"

cred <- OAuthFactory$new(consumerKey=my.key, consumerSecret=my.secret,
    requestURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token',
    accessURL = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token',
    authURL   = 'https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize')

Error: object 'OAuthFactory' not found
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Comment: `OAuthFactory ` is not in pkg:twitteR. I think errors cause by failing to load the package with a particular function should just be closed as equivalent to typos.

Answer (score 3):

I did some more research and found that I had to install two more packages that were not part of the twitteR package.  Here is what I needed and it worked:

```
install.packages(c('ROAuth','RCurl'))
require('ROAuth')
require('RCurl')
```

Thx

Comment: Using an answer to pose a question is not the SO way of doing things. Furthermore, asking fro package recs is one of the enumerated reasons for question closure. You should review the SO help pages.